# How to disable networking from command line without sudo?

Tags: networking, command-line, kde4

I want to disable networking from a bash script while not giving it administrative privileges. It's possible from GUI. Is there a way to do it from CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nmcli` to perform such operation:

```
nmcli nm enable false
```

`nmcli` [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/nmcli.1.html) pages:

```
          enable [true|false]
                 Get networking-enabled status or enable/disable
                 networking by NetworkManager.  All interfaces managed by
                 NetworkManager are deactivated when networking has been
                 disabled.
                 Reference to D-Bus:
                 interface: org.freedesktop.NetworkManager
                 method:    Enable
                 arguments: TRUE or FALSE
```

Comment: For me on Ubuntu 18.04 it is `nmcli n off`